# Efficient way of calculating this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there an efficient way for calculating the following?

Find the sum of all integer values of $y$ where $y=\frac { 1+\sqrt { 4x+1 }  }{ 2 } $ where $x$ is a positive integer in the range $0<x<100$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: To have $(1+\sqrt{4x+1})/2$ integer, you need $4x+1$ to be a square. Since $1\leq x\leq 99$, how many odd squares are in $[5,397]\cap\mathbb{N}$? There are quite few of them...

Since all odd squares are of the form $4k+1$ (since both $1^2\equiv 1$ and $3^2\equiv 1$ mod 4), any odd square in $[5,397]$ can be written as $4x+1$ some some integer $0<x<100$. Odd squares in $[5,397]$ are: $3^2,5^2,7^2,9^2,11^2,13^2,15^2,17^2,19^2$ (9 values).

Hence $\sqrt{4x+1}$ takes the values $3,5,7,\cdots,17,19$, and the total sum is
$$\frac{1+3}{2}+\frac{1+5}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1+19}{2}=2+3+4+\cdots+9+10=54. $$

Comment: But how did you get 1397?

Comment: Actually $[5,397]$ works (edited). $x$ in an integer with $0<x<100$, so the only integers having this are $\{1,2,\cdots,98,99\}$. Thus $4x+1$ has a minimum of $5=4\cdot 1+1$, maximum of $397=4\cdot 99+1$.

Comment: But why 5397? i get your idea about min of 5 and max of 397.

Comment: $[5,397]\cap \mathbb{N}$ means "all integers between 5 and 397" (i.e. $\{5,6,7,\cdots,396,397\}$).

Comment: Instead, couldn't we think in this way? For $y$ to be an integer (EDIT), we notice that in $\sqrt { 4x+1 } $ , $x$ must be even so that $\sqrt { 4x+1 } $ is odd so that when we add 1 to it, it becomes even and can be divided by $2$ to give an integer value for $y$.

Comment: Sure, that's the reason I said "...how many "odd" squares are in...". As you said $\sqrt{4x+1}$ needs to be odd integer, so $4x+1$ needs to be odd square (i.e. $x$ is even). There are less than 10 odd squares in $[5,397]$.

Comment: I get it now! Sorry it took me a while to understand. All i have to do is calculate all of them after adding $1$ and dividing by $2$. Is there a quicker way to do so? Or do i just have to do it?

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Milly! Appreciate your help!